# Assignment: expression or command?

Tags: bash

In Bash and Posix shells, there are many forms of commands, and an assignment is a form of command (specifically a simple command) if I am correct.

However `let` can be used in front of an assignment, and `let` is supposed to be used in front of an expression. So an assignment is also an expression, if I am correct.

What differences are between an assignment with and without `let` in front of it, both used as commands?  I am asking mainly about differences between their purposes, i.e. when to use which.
For example

```
$ aaa=1

$ let aaa=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let <EXPRESSION>`, while not POSIX-compliant itself, can be expressed in a POSIX conforming way as

```
[ "$(( <EXPRESSION> ))" -ne 0 ]
```

As opposed to the plain assignment, `let` also evaluates the assignment (expression) and returns an exit code depending on the result:

```
$ aaa=1; echo $?
0
$ aaa=0; echo $?
0

$ let aaa=1; echo $?
0
$ let aaa=0; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `let` is not [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) agrees:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
let a=3

$ shellcheck test.sh
In test.sh line 2:
let a=3
^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, 'let' is undefined.
```

---

The [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says:

> `((expression))`
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.   If  the  value of the
>   expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return
>   status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

and

> **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**
>
> The  shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances (see the let
>   and declare builtin commands and Arithmetic Expansion).  Evaluation is done 
>   in  fixed-width  integers  with  no  check  for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.  The
>   operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the C language.   The
>   following  list of operators is grouped into levels of equal-precedence operators.  The levels are
>   listed in order of decreasing precedence.
>
> …
>
> `= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &= ^= |=`
>                 assignment

and

> `let arg [arg ...]`
>   Each arg is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated (see ARITHMETIC
>   EVALUATION above).  If the last arg evaluates to 0, let returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.

So, in bash an assignment is also an expression and since you can evaluate one ore more expressions with `let`, you can do one ore more assignments with a single `let`. But, as noted above, it will not be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the documentation of `let`, right below where it says it takes an expression.

[let expression [expression …]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-let)

> The let builtin allows arithmetic to be performed on shell variables. **Each expression is evaluated according to the rules given below in [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).** If the last expression evaluates to 0, let returns 1; otherwise 0 is returned.

[Shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) includes assignment operators `=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `+=`, `-=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, and `|=`. This is not, in general, related to ordinary assignment statements, which do not apply any additional processing.

Comment: Thanks. what do you mean by "additional processing"?

Comment: "'Each expression is evaluated according to the rules given below in Shell Arithmetic"

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments are neither an expression or command, they are part of the "simple command" syntax.  Assignments can appear before a command word and modify the environment of that command.  If assignments appear without a command they modify the current shell's environment instead.

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html

See also this answer:
[What is this shell/Bash syntax: someVariable=someValue someCommand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334578/what-is-this-shell-bash-syntax-somevariable-somevalue-somecommand)

`let` is a Bash built-in command that implements it's own syntax and assignment operators, as @Michael Homer points out.  `help let` provides a handy reference.