# Why does an inline variable definition work but a previous line does not for an aws command?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, aws

When I run this command:

```
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com/ aws [aws-param]
```

the proxy is picked up by the `aws` command line tool.

However - when I do this:

```
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com/ 
aws [aws-param]
```

the `aws` command doesn't pick up the proxy.

To me, they're the same from a unix point of view. Is this something about the way python reads environment variables?

My question is: **Why does an inline variable definition work but a previous line does not for an aws command?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re not the same from a Unix point of view (or rather, from the shell’s point of view).

```
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com/ aws [aws-param]
```

defines the `https_proxy` variable explicitly for the `aws` command; the shell copies it to the `aws` process’s environment, and `aws` sees it.

```
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com/ 
aws [aws-param]
```

defines the variable in the shell’s environment, but because it’s not exported, the shell doesn’t copy it to the `aws` process’s environment.

The equivalent (from `aws`’s point of view) is actually

```
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com/ 
export https_proxy
aws [aws-param]
```

See [What is this Bash syntax: someVariable=someValue command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334578/86440) for more details (and links to the documentation).